# MANOVA (SPSS) test - determine control variables in moderation analysis

Tags: spss, causality, manova, controlling-for-a-variable, conditioning

I am examining the moderating effect of IV1 in the relationship between IV2 and DV using hierarchical regression analysis. The study has 2 demographic variables: gender and age. To determine if it is necessary to control these demographic variables, can I conduct MANOVA tests with IV1, IV2, and DV as dependent variables?

Comment: Controlling or not controlling for a variable is a topic squarely within the area of the New Causal Revolution. See this answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/590984/when-is-there-enough-or-too-much-balancing-in-observational-causal-studies/591001#591001.

Answer (score 0):

Your choice of control variables should be informed by the underlying causal model between the variables (as suggested in the comments). To specify such a causal model and read off what you need to adjust for, you can use tools such as the [dagitty](http://www.dagitty.net/) website/package.

For an introduction to causal models and how they can help in building the right sets of control variables, have a look at this [introduction to directed acyclic graphs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggdag/vignettes/intro-to-dags.html).